# What is the time complexity of creating a new Set from a given Array in JavaScript

Tags: ecmascript-6, set

More specifically, what would be the time complexity of the following

```
var mySet = new Set([1,2,3,4,5,6]) // n items in Array
    for (i=1 ; i<100 ; i++){
    if (!mySet.has(i)) return i
}
```

Comment: I would expect `O(n + 100)`, but that code is really weird. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Creating the set - `O(n)`. The rest of the code...uh, it's also `O(n)` (or `O(m)` if you want to signify it's different than the first) but not sure why it's there.